# what is necessary to connect a Zebra printer to Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, printing

I have a GC420t Zebra label printer and would like to connect it to the Pi 4 for printing information generated by a Python script. It is USB.

Have followed this guide https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/.cs.cmu.edu/help/content/printing/unix_linux_printing.html and also this one https://www.thegeekdiary.com/lpr-command-not-found/ which uses the command `lpr`, without success (I get no python errors when using `os.system('lpr ' + FileToPrint)`.

I also don't see the printer "mounted" on the Raspian desktop (as I see any USB stick). Any tips on why this does not work?

also: doing `sudo lpstat -s` https://smallbusiness.chron.com/list-printers-ubuntu-command-line-57593.html doesn't show any printer.

also: no other Q/A on this website helped me.

Comment: There are tools such as dmesg and lsusb which show what Linux knows about the device.

Comment: With search keywords "GC420t Zebra label printer linux" I found (among others) https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Adding-a-Zebra-Printer-in-a-CUPS-Printing-System?language=en_US

Comment: Mr Bodo, I have read and followed such guide before, but still nothing. Doing os.system('lpr -P GC420t ' + FileToPrint) returns "Unknown GC420t printer. I have set it to be my primary printer.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but it is a bit obtuse to discuss this in the context of a python system call when just using the CLI command is simpler, clearer, and more definitive.

Comment: *"The CUPS driver is directly built-in on the Mac OS and some Linux versions."* -> I'd take this to mean it involves proprietary source code that is not publicly available, and hence the driver only exists on platforms they distribute a binary for, and they don't do it for linux ARM systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out CUPS was the answer, I found and cofigured my printer using it: https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-print-in-raspberry-pi-using-cups/ . And also using `lp` instead of `lpr`: `os.system('lp -d GC420t '+ currentfile)` (where GC420t is my printer and currentfile holds the path to the field being printed.

Comment: Can you please share your python code which you are using to create ZPL file for Zebra printer? thanks.